# I am trying to plot a color based on conditional if statements, but cant seem to get the color to change based on counting

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Pine 5:

```
countval = 0
countval2 = 0
colorplot = color.yellow
colorplot2 = color.gray

// tracks last dirrection
if close > middle
    colorplot := color.green
    countval2 := countval2[1] + 1
if close <= middle
    colorplot := color.red
    countval2 := countval2[1] - 1

if countval2 > 15 or countval2 < 15
    countval2 := 0

// price within cloud
if close > lower and close < upper
    colorplot := colorplot[1]
    countval := 1


if countval2 < 0
    colorplot2 := color.red

if countval2 >= 0
    colorplot2 := color.green

plot(out2, color = colorplot, linewidth = 3)
plotshape(close, "range diamond", style = shape.diamond, location = location.abovebar, size =                                  
size.tiny, color = countval == 1 ?  colorplot2 : na)
```

The output is always green. Am I missing something?

I am trying to get price to count past 15 bars to determine weather it was bullish or bearish, and use the color red or green to show a shape when price is within a band based on an ema. The way I am writing it has some error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pinescript code is executed on each new bar close.
So on each new bar close your code set the countval value to zero because of this :

```
countval = 0
```

To initialize countval to 0 on the first bar only, you should use :

```
var countval = 0
```